# Develop a sub-websites (micro websites) in Codeignitter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Let's say I have a website called http://mysite.dev

### What I have:

So the urls of some pages will be below.

Home page: http://mysite.dev or http://mysite.dev/site/index or http://mysite.dev/home
(site/index has been routed to home)

Edit Profile: http://mysite.dev/user/edit or http://mysite.dev/edit-profile
(user/edit has been routed to edit-profile)

Admin Dashboard: http://mysite.dev/admin/ or http://mysite.dev/admin/index

Admin View Users: http://mysite.dev/admin/users or http://mysite.dev/admin/users/index

Admin Edit User: http://mysite.dev/admin/users/edit/1

So, basically my url pattern is as below.

**http://mysite.dev/{module}/{controller}/{action}/{params}**

### What I need:

While keeping the main site as above, I need to have sub websites (micro websites) which will share the same login in the main site.

So that, the url pattern would be as below.

**http://mysite.dev/{microsite}/{module}/{controller}/{action}/{params}**

(microsite is empty means its the main website. There will no be any directory to represent the microsite since its just a reference as a  name.)

That means, this microsite will not have sub directories since it the microsite name will be dynamic.

### What I need to know:

How can I implement that url pattern either using .htaccess or url routing to develop this dynamic microsites.

Thank you!

Comment: what makes the microsite a microsite? because if you don't have any other requirements than showing a view - e. g. no seperate dbs or tables - then {microsite} would just be another URI and you could either organize controllers in subdirs https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders or make routes to accomodate that

Comment: @mgrueter, this microsite name will be dynamic. That's why I'm facing a difficulty to use codeigniter routing to do this. And based on this microsite name, I will be loading separate dbs. But there is a common db which has got the user table, that's why there is global login.

Comment: I guess by "dynamic" you mean it could be whatever - because at some point you will need a check, to determine if this microsite exists and that means you need a list of microsites - be it as a set of routing rules or as an entry in a database (you'll also have to make sure, that your microsite can't be named something like "home" or "about-us"). So depending on your requirements, you either need to look into a multi-tenancy solution, or you can use wirezdesigne HMVW solution, or just solve this by having a set of controllers in subdirectories.

Comment: @mgrueter, you have get what is my requirement. Of course, this microsite name should be a valid name where I should be keep these list in somewhere, probable in a db table. It's better not to have seperate controllers, but I will try for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I have got my head around this one!

Firstly, you will need to organise the main site and each microsite into their own subdirectories (for controllers, models, views, etc), such as:

```
application/controllers/main_site/module/etc
application/controllers/micro_one/module/etc
application/controllers/micro_two/module/etc
```

Then inside the routes folder you would do something similar to the following pseudo code:

```
Create array of microsite names (maybe get these from database)

Get the first URI segment

If URI segment is in microsites array
  $route['home'] = "{uri_segment/microsite_name}/module/controller";
else
  $route['home'] = "main_site/module/controller";
```

So for example your microsites array may be:

```
array('micro_one', 'micro_two')
```

Then the URL http://mysite.dev/micro_one/home would route to

```
$route['home'] = "micro_one/home/index";
```

I hope I have explained this enough for you to get started on your project!

Comment: "you will need to organise the main site and each microsite into their own subdirectories (for controllers, models, views, etc)", is that mean i have to repeat and maintain the same code in each subdirectory? I hope it would not be practical.

Comment: Is it only the database connection that would need to change for each "microsite"?

Comment: Yes. Db connection need to changed and I must check whether that logged in user has the authority to view that microsite.